# Can't make String an instance of a class in Haskell

Tags: class, haskell

I'm playing around trying to understand classes in Haskell. 
I wrote a silly few lines of code to get the hang of it. I wrote a class called `Slang` that has one function. When I make Integer an instance of my class, it works fine. But when I make String an instance of my class it won't compile. I've been fidgeting with the program based on what the error output tells me but to no avail. I have idea why it work...

Here is the code followed by the error:

```
module Practice where

class Slang s where
    slangify :: s -> String

instance Slang Integer where
    slangify int = "yo"

instance Slang String where  -- When I take this segment out, it works fine
    slangify str = "bro"
```

ERROR:

```
Prelude> :load Practice
[1 of 1] Compiling Practice         ( Practice.hs, interpreted )

Practice.hs:9:10:
    Illegal instance declaration for `Slang String'
      (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
       where T is not a synonym.
       Use -XTypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for `Slang String'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that String is not a base type like Integer. What you are trying to do is actually

```
instance Slang [Char] where
    slangify str = "bro"
```

However, Haskell98 forbids this type of typeclass in order to keep things simple and to make it harder for people to write overlapping instances like

```
instance Slang [a] where
    -- Strings would also fit this definition.
    slangify list = "some list"
```

Anyway, as the error message suggests, you can get around this restriction by enabling the [FlexibleInstances](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/FlexibleInstances) extension.

Comment: Shameless plug for an old blog post I wrote exploring how the prelude gets around this limitation [in Show](http://brandon.si/code/how-the-haskell-prelude-avoids-overlapping-types-in-show/).

Comment: How do you enable FlexibleInstances?

Comment: @lmay: The easiest way to enable an extention is to add a comment like `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` to the top of your Haskell file.

Comment: It should also be noted that instead of `String` it's lately becoming conventional to use `Data.Text`, which is a base type and can have instances declared without any extensions.

Answer (score 5):

I did some research in my Haskell literature (aka my current Bible) and found an example that effectively solves my problem.

Basically, in this workaround you set `Char` to be an instance of the class (in the book's example it's called `Visible`) and then you can set `[chars]` aka a String, to be an instance of the class as well ONLY WITH the stipulation that the type variable `chars` be an instance of `Visible'.
It's easier to understand if you look at the code below:

```
module Practice where

class Visible a where
  toString :: a -> String
  size :: a -> Int

instance Visible Char where
  toString ch = [ch]
  size _ = 1

instance Visible a => Visible [a] where
  toString = concat . map toString
  size = foldr (+) 1 . map size
```

My GHCi load and function call:

```
*Practice> :l Practice
[1 of 1] Compiling Practice         ( Practice.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Practice.
*Practice> size "I love Stack!"
14
*Practice>
```

Eureka!

Comment: clever, but I think that only works if the only instance of this class is Char. If you create an instance with any other type, string-specific functions you use in the instance of Visible [a] will not work.

Comment: I didn't realize until after I had posted that comment that this thread was from 2013 :)